# Increase counter in a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, counter

Hello everyone i have a problem with a counter i have created in a for loop. Here is the code.

```
n1<- 0
n2<- 0
n<- 20
f<- rep(NA,20)
set.seed(10) 
x<- runif(20)
for(i in 1:20) {
f[i]<- ifelse(x[i]<0.5, 'a', 'b')
if((n1-n2)==2) {
break
 }
 if(f[i]=='a')  
n1<- n1 + 1 else n2<- n2 + 1 # n1 counts a's n2 counts b's
}

[1] "b" "a" "a" "b" "a" "a" "a" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

As you can see from the result number of a's=5 and b's=2 . But when i call n1 and n2 it returns 4 for n1 which is wrong . Why is that? How am I wrong ? Thanks in advance .

I start sampling a's and b's with probability 0.5 .20 total. At some point which i dont know in advance, the number of a's - the number of b's exceeds 2. When this happens i want the sampling probability to change to 0.2  Thats what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: You really need to learn to use `ifelse` properly. Using it in the middle of a for-loop like that is "just wrong".

Comment: If i dont and use sample instead how can i identify in the loop where the condition n1-n2==2 is satisfied? . How can i break the loop at exactly this point and continue to the next iteration changing the sample probability?

Comment: I wasn't saying to not use a for-loop (although I think you've already been given a much better alternative below). I was saying that using `ifelse()` with length-1 vectors was kind of silly. If you are using a loop, then you should be using `if(){}else{}`

Comment: I use ifelse here instead sample which may be wrong. But i still cant understand why a's and b's are not counted correctly in the loop

Comment: Printing out `x` and `f`, I don't see any error. What is not being "counted correctly". Perhaps you need to look at `?sum`.

Comment: I just did it. Thanks for your time .

Comment: So the basic problem appears to be that you are breaking out of the loop before the last count operation is completed?

Comment: Yes I think  . Breaking out of the loop would help me to spot the exact iteration where n1-n2 condition is satitsfied

Comment: Then you should increment any counters before the break.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ifelse` is vectorized so no need to use a `for-loop` here. This how you should use it:

```
set.seed(10) 
x <- runif(20)
f <- ifelse(x<0.5, 'a', 'b')
```

Then Use `table` to count occurrence:

```
table(f)
f
 a  b 
13  7
```

To get `n1` :

```
n1 <- table(f)[['a']]
```

**EDIT** OP wants to change the sample according to the occurrence of a and b. You should use `if` and `else` not `ifelse`. You should also preallocate memory for vector f.

```
n1 <- 0 ; n2 <- 0
N <- 20
f <- vector(mode='character',N)
set.seed(10)
x<- runif(N)
for(i in seq(N)) {
     if (x[i] <0.5){ 
        f[i] <- 'a'
        n1 <- n1 +1
     } else {
        f[i] <- 'b'
        n2 <- n2 +1
     }
    if((n1-n2)==2) x <- runif(N)  ## condition to regenerate sample
}
```

Comment: I use a for loop because i want to identify in which step the condition n1-n2==2 is satisfied. That's why i am trying to count a's and b's separately . I want to use their difference as a condition in the loop .

Comment: I want to know the difference between a's and b's at every step of my loop so i can break i when a's-b's=2

Comment: @Manos it is exactly what I did.

Comment: I just saw it thanks a lot . So after the condition i can change the sample probability to 0.2 right?

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted . Thanks a lot agstudy for your help. it was really enlightening!